# windows phone 7 image checkbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to create a simple checkbox, which is an image instead of the classic one. I managed to create the control and assign it different behaviours, but I can't make it to work when checking/unchecking. Here's the code :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckboxImageTemplate" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Image Name="imgTreble" MinWidth="100" Source="Images/treble_unchecked.png"/>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>


<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
        <CheckBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="checkBox1" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{StaticResource CheckboxImageTemplate}" >
            <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                    <ic:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" TargetName="imgTreble" Value="Images/treble_checked.png"/>
                </Custom:EventTrigger>
                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                    <ic:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" TargetName="imgTreble" Value="Images/treble_unchecked.png"/>
                </Custom:EventTrigger>
            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

I think that the problem's that I'm trying to change a property for one of the control's (in this case, the checkbox) controltemplate's items (the image). There's probably a problem with TargetName, and I should be referencing in a different way how to tell the EventTrigger to look for the image and change its source, but I don't know how
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that purpose you need to use VisualStates in your checkbox's ControlTemplate.

[Here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-working-with-VisualStates-How-to-make-a-ToggleSwitch-from-CheckBox) is a very good article that customizes a checkbox to act as toggle button.

[WP7 working with VisualStates: How to make a ToggleSwitch from CheckBox](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-working-with-VisualStates-How-to-make-a-ToggleSwitch-from-CheckBox)

You can use the same method to present images for each visual state.

Comment: Here is one more approach: http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Custom-Styles-and-Templates-in-Windows-Phone-CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this, you should retemplate (set a custom style on) the checkbox to achieve your desired output.

In the custom style, use the "Checked" VisualState to hide and show the appropriate images.