# Windows Phone ControlTemplate & Converter : problem loading BitmapImage from Image Resource in assembly

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

This is basically a follow up to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667916/windows-phone-7-image-checkbox) question.
I've managed to make this work with the templates, however, I want to make it a bit generic, so that I don't have to go around repeating code all over the place

The working version (hardcoded) is this :

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TrebleCheckboxImageTemplate" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Image x:Name="imgTreble" MinWidth="100" Source="Images/treble_checked.png">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="imgTreble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/treble_checked.png" />
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="imgTreble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/treble_unchecked.png" />
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>                           
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Image>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>


<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{StaticResource TrebleCheckboxImageTemplate}" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Command="{Binding TreblePressedCommand}"/>
                </Custom:EventTrigger>
            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>

    </StackPanel>
```

Of course, the image paths are hardcoded. So, i wanted to make it generic, so that you could just instantiate a checkbox, tell it it's image, and the template would be the same for all.

I created an ImageCheckbox control class :

```
public class ImageCheckbox : CheckBox
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="CheckedImagePath" /> dependency property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string CheckedImagePathPropertyName = "CheckedImagePath";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="CheckedImagePath" />
        /// property. This is a dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public string CheckedImagePath
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(CheckedImagePathProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CheckedImagePathProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="CheckedImagePath" /> dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedImagePathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            CheckedImagePathPropertyName,
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ImageCheckbox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));


        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="UnCheckedImagePath" /> dependency property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string UnCheckedImagePathPropertyName = "UnCheckedImagePath";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="UnCheckedImagePath" />
        /// property. This is a dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public string UnCheckedImagePath
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(UnCheckedImagePathProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(UnCheckedImagePathProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="UnCheckedImagePath" /> dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UnCheckedImagePathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            UnCheckedImagePathPropertyName,
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ImageCheckbox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));


    }
```

I created a converter (because I ran into the problem that I must convert the string to be the Uri for the image source)

```
public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
            {
                UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser
                    (GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
            }

            if (value is string)
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.UriSource = new Uri(String.Format(@"pack://application:,,/Images/{0}", value as string));
                //image.UriSource = new Uri(String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/Adagio.Presentation;component/Images/{0}", value as string),UriKind.Absolute);
                image.ImageFailed += new EventHandler<System.Windows.ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(image_ImageFailed);
                image.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs>(image_ImageOpened);
                return image;
            }

            if (value is Uri)
            {
                var bi = new BitmapImage {UriSource = (Uri) value};
                return bi;
            }
            return null;
        }

        void image_ImageOpened(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void image_ImageFailed(object sender, System.Windows.ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

you can see that the converter has been tried with thousands of different combinations, none of them work...
Then, the new xaml :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckboxImageTemplate" TargetType="Controls:ImageCheckbox">
            <Image x:Name="imgForTemplate" MinWidth="100" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=CheckedImagePath, Converter={StaticResource stringToImageConverter}}">
                <!--
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="imgForTemplate"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=CheckedImagePath, Converter={StaticResource stringToImageConverter}}" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="imgForTemplate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=UnCheckedImagePath, Converter={StaticResource stringToImageConverter}}" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>-->
            </Image>

        </ControlTemplate>

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Controls:ImageCheckbox CheckedImagePath="treble_checked.png" UnCheckedImagePath="treble_unchecked.png" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{StaticResource CheckboxImageTemplate}" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Command="{Binding TreblePressedCommand}"/>
                </Custom:EventTrigger>
            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Controls:ImageCheckbox>

    </StackPanel>
```

I've tried to make it all work at first, but I don't seem to even get the first Source property of the image to load. The commented part (VisualStateManager states) doesn't work either, but i think it must be the same problem.. in this case I'd need a converter to return an Uri instead of a BitmapImage, because UriSource is of type Uri, and Source is of type Image.
I'm getting errors in the converter, where I can't load the images (always falling into the image_imageFailed event). I've set the images as resources in the assembly... what am i doing wrong?? this is driving me crazy!!!!

[EDIT] : I've tried doing as suggested, and changed the dependency property to Uri, but I can't get it to work
If i say

```
<Controls:ImageCheckbox CheckedImagePath="Images/treble_checked.png" UnCheckedImagePath="Images/treble_unchecked.png" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{StaticResource CheckboxImageTemplate}" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
```

and in the template's VisualState :

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=UnCheckedImagePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

it tells me that the xaml isn't valid and get an error. If i use TemplateBinding like this :

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{TemplateBinding UnCheckedImagePath}" />
```

it doesn't complain, but the image doesn't load (appear blank). I think i'm getting close, but still haven't found the solution...

[EDIT 2] : last try...

usage :

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Controls:ImageCheckbox Style="{StaticResource TheImageCheckboxStyle}" CheckedImagePath="Images/treble_checked.png" UnCheckedImagePath="Images/treble_unchecked.png" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Command="{Binding TreblePressedCommand}"/>
                </Custom:EventTrigger>
            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Controls:ImageCheckbox>

    </StackPanel>
```

style (trying to copy what you pasted and removing what i thought are unnecessary parts)

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="TheImageCheckboxStyle" TargetType="Controls:ImageCheckbox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                                   
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                                <!--  Magic!  -->
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CheckedImagePath}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                                <!--  Magic!  -->
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=UnCheckedImagePath}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="CheckBackground"
                                        Width="32"
                                        Height="32"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateMark"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Width="16"
                                           Height="16"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <!--  Magic! Default to UnCheckedImagePath  -->
                                <Image x:Name="CheckMark"
                                       Width="24"
                                       Height="18"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=UnCheckedImagePath}"
                                       Stretch="Fill"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the type of CheckedImagePath to Uri, and just binding directly to that, instead of creating a BitmapImage ?

As I see it, your code is vastly overcomplicating a simple binding.

Edit: Here's how I would do it (working example)

**Use Example**

```
<local:ImageCheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     CheckedImagePath="CheckedImage.png"
                     Content="CheckBox"
                     UnCheckedImagePath="UnCheckedImage.png" />
```

**C#**

```
public partial class ImageCheckBox // NameSpace: MyControls
{
    public ImageCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public const string CheckedImagePathPropertyName = "CheckedImagePath";

    public Uri CheckedImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return (Uri)GetValue(CheckedImagePathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CheckedImagePathProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedImagePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(CheckedImagePathPropertyName,
            typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public const string UnCheckedImagePathPropertyName = "UnCheckedImagePath";

    public Uri UnCheckedImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return (Uri)GetValue(UnCheckedImagePathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UnCheckedImagePathProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnCheckedImagePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(UnCheckedImagePathPropertyName, 
            typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

**XAML** (Look for "Magic!" for the relevant parts)

```
<CheckBox x:Class="MyControls.ImageCheckBox"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WindowsPhoneApplication1"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          d:DesignHeight="480"
          d:DesignWidth="480"
          mc:Ignorable="d">
    <CheckBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase"
               TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                                    Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    CornerRadius="0">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}"
               TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}"
               TargetType="l:ImageCheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBorderBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                                <!--  Magic!  -->
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CheckedImagePath}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                                <!--  Magic!  -->
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=UnCheckedImagePath}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="CheckBackground"
                                        Width="32"
                                        Height="32"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateMark"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Width="16"
                                           Height="16"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <!--  Magic! Default to UnCheckedImagePath  -->
                                <Image x:Name="CheckMark"
                                       Width="24"
                                       Height="18"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=UnCheckedImagePath}"
                                       Stretch="Fill"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: could you post a sample on how to do it please? i wouldn't know how to change both the image source & also the visualstates to make it work.

Comment: I followed your advice and tried something else, please take a look at my edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: See updated post for example. -- Also, I would recommend that you use the style instead of using a UserControl, if you intend to render many of these. UserControl can usually not be virtualized, and generally have bad performance.

Comment: wow, there's tons of code here.. i guess that you copied the original full template for the control and then added the other stuff. i'll give it a try and let you know, thx

Comment: I just had Expression Blend autogenerate it for me ;-)

Comment: that's cool, however, it's a ton of code. i know that you pointed out the important parts, but i tried creating a style with them and it doesn't work. i need some specific guidance here, since it's probably a very minor issue in the xaml that's not working, but i keep getting the AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE  error. i'll post the current xaml code (the ImageCheckBox class is exactly the same as the one you posted)

Comment: Well, from a pure fragment point of view it's difficult to see if your error is related to the posted code at all. Have you tried without the EventToCommand binding?

Comment: yes, i've tried. anyway, that's not the problem, because that was working before (with the 1st version, hardcoded values). and if that were the problem, i still need the command to work :P

Comment: Yes, but your problem is still related to the *rest* of your code. Also, I don't see why you're using a UserControl for this, when it's much easier, and more performant to just retemplate a regular CheckBox. If you compare your orginal way of doing the bindings it's identical to how I did it. So most likely the entire problem is related to the way you're using it. A wild guess says that you can't use TemplateBinding. You should check with Expression Blend for details.

Comment: well, i'm using a usercontrol because i want to make it available in several parts of the application, i don't want to retemplate the checkbox everywhere i need it.. that's what usercontrols are for, aren't they? Expression blend (and vs) don't like the Binding inside the controltemplate. i'll give it some more tries, however, i don't find it a good solution to have 1000 lines of code like that to just create a clickable image checkbox....

Comment: ok, i've created everything from scratch. I've generated the full template IN the page (no usercontrol), added the image with the source (didn't touch the visualstates). so far so good, the image doesn't change. i added the visualstates, but i'm getting a AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE when clicking on the image. your code CAN't work because you replaced the checkmark with the image (same x:name), and an Image doesn't have a Fill property, and in your code you're setting a Fill through a VisualState... so you either didn't click the image, or didn't post the final code.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1763/discussion-between-daniel-perez-and-claus-jorgensen)